# App crashes with java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo error

Tags: java, android, xml, syntax-error, logcat

My app has worked before but now the app won't boot up correctly. When the App does boot up to `homebck.xml` (which I will include the source code below) it automatically crashes and in a Toast it says the `crash_toast_text` in the `strings.xml`.

Also it is not just a Toast that Appears also a Share Tray Ex. 
[image]

That pops up every single time. Below I have posted the files I think are necessary to help me out!

Error Log:

```
06-03 18:27:11.420    9762-9762/com.Celebration E/ACRA﹕ ACRA caught a RuntimeException for com.Celebration
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Celebration/com.abode.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
            at com.abode.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:155)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Only a Snippet of MainActivity.java due to the 30000 character limit:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    public static File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "");
    public static Item[] fileList;
    public static Boolean firstLvl = true;
    public static ListAdapter adapter;
    private final int FileUpload = 100;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public static final String URL = "http://celebration.anazro.com/appData/images/celebration.jpg";
    public static final String URL1 = "http://celebration.anazro.com/appData/images/celebration2.jpg";
    public static final String URL2 = "http://celebration.anazro.com/appData/images/celebration3.jpg";
    public static final String URL3 = "http://celebration.anazro.com/appData/images/celebration4.jpg";
    public static final String URL4 = "http://celebration.anazro.com/appData/images/celebration5.jpg";
   // public static final String URL5 = "";
   // public static final String URL6 = "";
   // public static final String URL7 = "";
    public static String chosenFile;
    public static ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static String ss;
    public AboutPopup aboutPopup;


    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    //old code
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    private NavDrawerListAdapter navAdapter;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View viewForPopup;
    public AlarmManager alarm;
    //experiment code
    public static  LiveSdkSampleApplication myContextManager;

    public static WeakReference wrActivity = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);
        wrActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(this);

        Globals.application = getApplication();
        myContextManager = ((LiveSdkSampleApplication) getApplicationContext());
        myContextManager.setContext(this);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        viewForPopup = (View)findViewById(R.id.view);
         alarm = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1)));
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        navAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(navAdapter);
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
       // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.side_bar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    //A method found in stackOverflow, don't remember the author, to determine the right screen orientation independently of the phone or tablet device


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(fragment)
                .attach(fragment)
                .commit();

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       /* int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }*/
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home: {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                break;
            }

            case R.id.admin:{
                AdminPopup adminPopup = new AdminPopup(this);
                adminPopup.showAtLocation(viewForPopup,0,0);
                break;
            }



        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
```

This is the XML Code to the Slideshow:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/homefragment"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_information"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_information"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_save"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_wallpaper"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This would be the last it is the Java file for the Slideshow

```
public class SlideShow extends Fragment {

   // Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
   public static final String URL =
           "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg";
    ViewPager m_viewPager;
    NetworkImageAdapter m_adapter;
    ImageAdapter m_ImageAdapter;
    ArrayList<NetworkImageView> m_NetworkImageViews;
    ArrayList<ImageView> m_ImageView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Context context;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = getActivity();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slideshow, container, false);
        m_viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slide_view_pager);
        m_NetworkImageViews = new ArrayList<NetworkImageView>();
        m_NetworkImageViews.clear();

        NetworkImageView m_newworkImageView = new NetworkImageView(context);
        m_newworkImageView.setImageUrl(URL, imageLoader);
        m_NetworkImageViews.add(m_newworkImageView);
        m_adapter = new NetworkImageAdapter(m_NetworkImageViews);


        //m_ImageView = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        //imageView = new ImageView(context);


 /*       GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        // Execute the task
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });
*/


        return rootView;
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } // Autho



    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap map = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                map = downloadImage(url);
            }
            return map;
        }

        // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            m_ImageView.add(imageView);
            m_ImageAdapter  = new ImageAdapter(m_ImageView);
            m_viewPager.setAdapter(m_ImageAdapter);

        }

        // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
        private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

            try {
                stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                        decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: Try looking at line 155 of MainActivity.java: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1)));
```

And consider replacing that block of near-identical calls with a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(fragment)
                .attach(fragment)
                .commit();

    }
```

The code must be changed following code:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .detach(fragment)
                        .attach(fragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```